# Getting exception “java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Double cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector” During dataset creation

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

We are getting exception

> “java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Double cannot be cast to
>   org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector”

During dataset creation

```
List<Row> setData = new ArrayList<>();
StructType schemasetData = new StructType( new StructField[] 
 {
  new StructField("IsMatch", DataTypes.StringType, false,Metadata.empty()),
  new StructField("combinedscore", new  VectorUDT(), false,Metadata.empty()),
  new StructField("ProductDescriptionScore1", DataTypes.StringType, false,Metadata.empty()),
  new StructField("ProductDescriptionScore2", DataTypes.StringType, false,Metadata.empty()),
  new StructField("ProductDescriptionScore3", DataTypes.StringType, false,Metadata.empty()),
  new StructField("ProductDescriptionScore4", DataTypes.StringType, false,Metadata.empty()),
  new StructField("ProductDescriptionScore5", DataTypes.StringType, false,Metadata.empty()),
  new StructField("ManufacturerScore1", DataTypes.StringType, false,Metadata.empty()),
  new StructField("ManufacturerScore2", DataTypes.StringType, false,Metadata.empty()),
  new StructField("ManufacturerScore3", DataTypes.StringType, false,Metadata.empty()),
 });Dataset<Row> dataset = sparkSession.createDataFrame(setData, schemaSetData);
```

Is it an issue in spark. Or how to handle double in Schema vector.

Comment: Can you share a sample of the data? What exactly is `combinedscore`?